# How to convert excel number format value to number in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-5

We are reading number values from excel sheet and converting to number in rails using regex

Conversion should happen as follows

```
$10000.00 = 10000.00
10000.00 = 10000.00
$(10000) = -10000
$10,000 = 10000
$(10,000) = -10000
-$10,000 = -10000
```

Currently i am using regex **value.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9.-]+/, '')** but its missing parantheses clause.
Any pointer to cover $(10000) this case

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm the string matches the required format by attempting to match the regular expression

```
R = /\A-?\$?(?=\(?(?<dollars>[1-9](?:\d*|\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{2})?)\)?$)(?:\k<dollars>|\(\k<dollars>\))\z/
```

If it does match named capture group `dollars` will hold the correctly formatted string with the possible exception of a leading minus sign. The minus sign is prepended to the string if the string matches the regular expression

```
/\A\$?[-\(]/
```

```
def reformat(str)
  m = R.match(str)
  return nil if m.nil?
  (str.match?(/\A\$?[-\(]/) ? '-' : '') + m[:dollars]
end
```

---

```
reformat "1000"             #=> "1000"
reformat "10000.00"         #=> "10000.00"
reformat "10,000"           #=> "10000"
reformat "-10,000.00"       #=> "-10000.00"
reformat "$10000"           #=> "10000"
reformat "$10000.00"        #=> "10000.00"
reformat "-$10,000.00"      #=> "-10000.00"
reformat "(10000)"          #=> "-10000"
reformat "$(10000)"         #=> "-10000"
reformat "$(10,000)"        #=> "-10000"
reformat "$(10,000.00)"     #=> "-10000"

reformat "10000.0"          #=> nil 
reformat "10000.000"        #=> nil
reformat "$(10,000,000.00"  #=> nil
reformat "$10,000,000.00)"  #=> nil
```

See [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/s3URseXYIzlkyW) and [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5gc3Fz/1).

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows. Note the positive lookahead saves the absolute dollar amount to capture group `dollars`. That value is later backreferenced twice.

```
\A              # match beginning of string
-?              # optionally match '$'
\$?             # optionally match '$' 
(?=             # begin a positive lookahead
  \(?           # optionally match '?'
  (?<dollars>   # begin capture group 'dollars'
    [1-9]       # match a digit 0-9
    (?:         # begin a non-capture group
      \d*       # match zero or more digits
      |         # or
      \d{0,2}   # match 0-2 digits
      (?:       # begin a non-capture group
        ,       # match ','
        \d{3}   # match three digits
      )*        # end non-capture group and execute zero or more times
    )           # end non-capture group
    (?:         # begin a non-capture group
      \.\d{2}   # match '.' followed by two digits
    )?          # end non-capture group and make it optional
  )             # end capture group 'dollars          
  \)?           # optionally match ')'
  $             # match end of string
)               # end positive lookahead
(?:             # begin a non-capture group
  \k<dollars>   # match contents of group named 'dollars'
  |             # or
  \(            # match '('
  \k<dollars>   # match contents of group named 'dollars'
  \)            # match ')'
)               # end non-capture group
\z              # match end of string
```

---

If you are confident that the string will have a correct format you do not need to use a regular expression.

```
def reformat(str)
  str.delete('$,)').sub('(','-')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take out any value between parentheses and place a `-` sign at the start of that string, and then remove all chars other than digits, `-` and `.`:

```rb
.sub(/\A(.*?)\(([^()]*)\)/, '-\1\2').gsub(/[^0-9.-]+/, '')
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/yXebJP):

```rb
vals = ['$10000.00', '10000.00', '$(10000)', '$10,000', '$(10,000)', '-$10,000']
puts vals.map { |m| m.sub(/\A(.*?)\(([^()]*)\)/, '-\1\2').gsub(/[^0-9.-]+/, '') }
```

Output:

```
# ['10000.00', '10000.00', '-10000', '10000', '-10000', '-10000']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xeEoSN/1). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` chars
- `\)`  - a `)` char.

The replacement is a concatenation of a `-` char, Group 1 and Group 2 values.